# python - replacing pd.rolling_apply in codes

Tags: python, pandas

I am referring to codes in the below link
[Identifying Extrema in Financial Data using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799408/identifying-extrema-in-financial-data-using-pandas)

One of the functions has below code

```
def bear_market(symbol, window=90, correction = .2):
    return pd.rolling_apply(symbol, window, lambda x: x[-1]/x.max() < (1-correction))
```

it seems rolling_apply is now replaced by rolling in python, but I am still struggling to amend this code

```
pd.rolling_apply(symbol, window, lambda x: x[-1]/x.max() < (1-correction))
```

can someone help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`Series.rolling()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) takes the `window` param and [**`Rolling.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) takes the lambda:

```py
def bear_market(symbol, window=90, correction=0.2):
    return symbol.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: x[-1]/x.max() < (1-correction))
```